# Any alternative available of sudzc for java?

Tags: java, web-services, android-ksoap2, sudzc

[sudzc](http://sudzc.com/) is a very good online tool to get a bundled API for sending request to a SOAP service and get response from service using WSDL link of that webservice. I want to know is there is anything available like sudzc for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also looking for something like this - there seem to be plenty of WSDL-to-Java utilities out there but most are unmaintained or don't support Android. The closest I can find is this [Android ksoap2 stub generator](http://www.davidgouveia.net/android-ksoap2-stub-generator/). It appears like the perfect thing but I've not had a great deal of success with it (the generated code is very hit-or-miss), but that might be my WSDL files. Hopefully you have more luck with it.

Comment: Wow, It generated all the methods and Configuration class successfully for me. I will use it in my next project. Thank you.

Comment: @blork  is asmx differ from wsdl?

Answer (score 1):

Would [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) do what you need? It's very useful as an interactive testing tool, but it also interfaces with different Java libraries (Axis, Jax, etc) to create Web Services Java code.

Comment: It's a v.nice tool. But generating methods from a Wsdl link I don't see in its features. And it's too heavy for this kind of work. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Under File/Preferences, Tools, set up the path to the tools you want to use (JAX, Axis, .NET, Xfire, CXF, etc). Then pick what kind of artifacts you want from the Tools menu.